# Autofac registration error: The type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' is not an open generic class or interface type

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I try to register the `IPage<>` interface with Autofac, but it always throws the following exception:

> The type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' is not an open generic class or interface type.

This is my code:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<>)))
                .AsSelf()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

My Interface and the implementation:

```
public interface IPage<T> : IList<T>
{
}

public interface Page<T> : List<T>, IPage<T>
{
}
```

Can you help me understand why this happens and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`IList<T>` inherits from and `IEnumerable`. calling `.AsImplementedInterfaces()` on your types is like calling `.As<IList<T>>().As<IPage>().As<IEnumerable<T>>().As<ICollection<T>>().As<IEnumerable>()` I don't know exactly why but *Autofac* try to register `IEnumerable` as a closed type and it fails.

If you want to resolve `IPage<T>` you don't have to register your types with `.AsImplementedInterfaces()` you have to register it as a closed type :

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IPage<>));
```

Then when you resolve `IPage<Customer>`, *Autofac* will give you a `Page<Customer>` instance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IList<>));
```

`AsClosedTypesOf` specifies that a type from a scanned assembly is registered if it implements an interface that closes the provided open generic interface type.